# difference between two strings mysql

Tags: mysql, string, difference

I want to find the difference between two strings in MySQL. Say, if two strings like nishant and nisha are input, then 'nt' should be output.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Also, you need to define "difference" a little better; what if "foo" and "bar" are the inputs, what do you expect then?

Comment: You should clarify: what if you have `aaaabc` and `bc`? Would the output be empty? And what if you have `a` and `c`? etc etc. (do it in your question, not in a comment). Does repetition count, does order count, what type is your field...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set @string2 :="nishant";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

set @string1 := "nisha";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

select @string1, @string2;
+----------+----------+
| @string1 | @string2 |
+----------+----------+
| nisha    | nishant  |
+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

select if(length(@string1)>length(@string2), replace(@string1, @string2,""), replace(@string2, @string1, "")) as "The Difference";
+----------------+
| The Difference |
+----------------+
| nt             |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```